# How to install "gotests" command?

Tags: go

I need to use the test driven development in Go using "gotests" command.

```
gotests -all *
```

This is not working. I did `go get -u /github.com/cweill/gotests`
and `go install`. But there is no binary created in `$GOPATH/bin`.

Comment: "github.com/cweill/gotests" is not a "main" package, so there is no binary artifact.

Comment: The command to install, from the [Installation section in the README](https://github.com/cweill/gotests#installation) is `$ go get -u github.com/cweill/gotests/...`

Comment: If there is no binary artifact how we should use the gotests command from the command Line as mentioned in the https://github.com/cweill/gotests#installation section

Comment: The command in the README is not what you executed. The "main" package is in a subdirectory you haven't installed.

Comment: Thanks this helped:)

Answer (score 8):

The following worked for me with go v1.19.1

```
go install github.com/cweill/gotests/gotests@latest
```

Using `go get` to install things has been disabled since 1.18. See [Deprecation of 'go get' for installing executables](https://go.dev/doc/go-get-install-deprecation)

Comment: Thank you! It was not at all obvious you have to have `gotests` twice in the URL.

Comment: Thanks for the link as well. I've come across this for a lot of older go related code, and this solidified my understanding of the change - thanks!

Answer (score 6):

since there is NO main package, Use this command

```
$ go get github.com/cweill/gotests/...
```

this itself download all dependencies for the current package, and creates bin file, after downloading this package. see in $GOPATH/bin there will be a bin file named **gotests**

for more see [HERE](https://github.com/alco/gostart#10-how-do-i-download-remote-packages)

Comment: what to do with bin file named gotests?

Answer (score 0):

```
go install github.com/rakyll/gotest
```

Source: https://github.com/rakyll/gotest

Comment: It should be: `go install github.com/cweill/gotests/gotests@latest`. You have the wrong package. It's not gotest but gotests.